# Git feature branch review : Rewrite or add commit?

Tags: git, git-flow

Let's say a feature branch has the following history :

- (4) Change D to use B and A
- (3) Change C to use A
- (2) Add B
- (1) Add A

After review, it is decided that "B" should not make it to develop.

Should you

**1- `rebase -i`, rewrite history/some code so that the feature branch, after a force push, becomes:**

- (7) Change D to use A
- (6) Change C to use A
- (5) Add A

or

**2- Add a commit that gets rid of the rejected feature and push, giving:**

- (5) Get rid of B
- (4) Change D to use B and A
- (3) Change C to use A
- (2) Add B
- (1) Add A

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`force push` is never advisable in a collaborative environment since it impacts the local repos of your team mates, so I always try to avoid it.

My preference normally goes to preserving the “history” :) of our decisions in the commit history, so in this case option (2) would be my preference, especially since you can directly `git revert` commit #2 *(and add another one to remove it from D, of course)*.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer cleaner history or it is easier - then rebase. Otherwise the revert would do as well.